# Как создать подсказки

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

Вся суть:
1. Пользователь заполняет форму
2. Скрипт чекает содержимое формы и если оно не корректно - выводит подсказку под форму 
(пример: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] )
Как это можно реализовать? Думаю, что с JS можно, но не знаю как

Comment: Под каждым input полем создаешь пустой span с красным цветом текста. Проверяешь пароль регуляркой с помощью .test(str) и если test вернул false, то с innerHTML или с html() вставляешь нужный текст в span. Не забудь проверять пароль и на стороне сервера.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let psw = document.querySelector('#psw');
let pswCheck = document.querySelector('#psw-check');
pswCheck.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (psw.value !== pswCheck.value) {
    document.querySelector('.error').textContent = 'Ошибка! Пароли не совпадают!';
  }
})
```

```css
.error {
  color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<input type="password" id="psw">
<input type="password" id="psw-check">
<div class="error"></div>
```

Comment: Стилизовать можно на своё усмотрение. Я не заморачивался.

Comment: Я бы повесил обработчик события change на оба input`а, а то мало ли пользователь начал изменять первый input и ввел идентичный пароль и ошибка должна пропасть. И добавить возможность скрыть эту ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

1) Само это поле с подсказкой (красным цветом или еще каким), в html прописать с аттрибутом hidden. Таким образом, пока поле пароля не будут трогать, подсказка будет невидимой. Предположим, мы задали ему id = 'popup'
2) Если, к примеру, использовать jquery (да и не только с ним), можно написать функцию, которая при событии change на поле пароля, будет выполнять проверку, и делать видимым ( $('#popup').show()) поле с id = popup. Как только введут неверный пароль, она покажется. Кстати, чтобы показалась красиво, можно вместо show() прописать fadeIn().

P.S. Можно также в css прописать красивые аттрибуты для класса всплывающей подсказки (назовем для примера 'popup_on', а также прописать единственный аттрибут 'display: none;' для класса скрытой подсказки ('popup_off'). И при событии change менять эти классы.